# What mean "(no architecture available)" in iOS API Diffs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

anyone can answer to this beautiful question? :D I need to use one of the method that have this phrase but Xcode doesn't detect it :/.

Comment: For iOS 6 questions you must go to the Apple developer forums. It is still under NDA

Comment: @PauldeLange It wasn't a great title, but this question isn't specific to iOS 6.  In fact with a quick rename of the title, the question is now generic ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to include a header....

EDIT:  I figured out what that message means.  It means that it has been added into the header, but is not available for iOS yet so you can't  use it.

Comment: And you put `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` at the top?

Comment: Yep dude (thanks for the help). Xcode say: Unknown type name 'AVCaptureScreenInput'